# sequelize-typescript - When using glob configuration with `tsc` compiler (with NestJS) cannot resolve model modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am setting up `sequelize-typescript` and then adding models:

```
    import appRoot from 'app-root-path'

    connection = new Sequelize({... connection details})
    const appGlobPattern = join(appRoot.toString(), 'src/**/entities/*.entity.ts')
    // appGlobPattern = absolute path to the root of the project (i.e. C:/Users/user/my-project/)
    this.connection.addModels([appGlobPattern])
```

An error is thrown when trying to do the `require(fullPath)` line in `sequelize-service` (https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/blob/1c34e87c968b1c8333ef6467c2dd44e069e06fa8/src/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize-service.ts#L57)

An error is thrown as the file resolver cannot resolve the file (which exists):

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\my-project\src\entities\my-model.entity'

Full stack track

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\........\notification\entities\communication-channel.entity'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at glob.sync.filter.map.filter.map.fullPath (C:\Users\........\notification\node_modules\sequelize-typescript\dist\sequelize\sequelize\sequelize-service.js:44:32)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at arg.reduce (C:\Users\........\notification\node_modules\sequelize-typescript\dist\sequelize\sequelize\sequelize-service.js:43:18)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Object.getModels (C:\Users\........\notification\node_modules\sequelize-typescript\dist\sequelize\sequelize\sequelize-service.js:35:20)
    at Sequelize.addModels (C:\Users\........\notification\node_modules\sequelize-typescript\dist\sequelize\sequelize\sequelize.js:34:44)
    at DatabaseConnection._addModelsToConnection (C:\Users\........\notificationn\dist\database\classes\database-connection.js:33:25)
    at DatabaseConnection.createConnection (C:\Users\........\notification\dist\database\classes\database-connection.js:23:14)
    at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (C:\Users\........\notification\dist\database\providers\database-connection-pool.provider.js:13:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

It seems to potentially be something with the tsc compiler that NestJS is using by default. Or perhaps module loader does not play nice with absolute file paths.

---

More details:

- sequelize: "version": "5.21.2"
- sequelize-typescript: "version": "1.0.0"
- typescript "version": "3.7.2"

These are my tsconfig settings:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "express": ["src/multi-tenancy/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `src` as part of your file path, as once you compile the code from Typescript to JavaScript, your code now lives in `dist` and the `src` folder is lost in the context. You should also change the `.ts` to `.js` as that's what files will be resolved at runtime. The other option is to use a glob like `join(__dirname, '{dist,src}/**/entities/*.entity.{js,ts}')` so that you can look at both without changing your code between `src` and `dist`.

Note: `join` is from the `path` module

Comment: OMG, I actually just stumbled upon this too. Was able to get it working with `'/dist/**/entities/*.entity.js'`. Was not able to use the `{dist,src}/**/entities/*.entity.{js,ts}` with seqeulize-typescript though (gave me same error)

Comment: Probably still trying to work with the src directory, which it definitely shouldn't. Oh, yeah, I usually use `__dirname` with it, and the `join` function from the `path` module. I'll update the answer to have that.